# move a line to the beginning of a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I try to run this test:

```
@Test
public void moveLastUpdateToFirstLine() throws Exception {
    StringUtils stringUtils = new StringUtils();
    String newString = stringUtils.moveLastUpdateToFirstLine("bbbbbbb last_update : 188908098 cccc");
    assert (newString.equals("last_update : 188908098 bbbbbbb cccc"));
}



public String moveLastUpdateToFirstLine(String venueConfigurationStr) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(last_update : \\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(venueConfigurationStr);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        venueConfigurationStr = matcher.group(1) + venueConfigurationStr.replace(matcher.group(1), "");
    }
    return venueConfigurationStr;
}
```

but it says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
```

how can i fix my matcher?

Comment: Can you check matcher.matches() instead of matcher.find()?

Comment: Your `Pattern` is expecting to match a whole line. Either surround it with `.*` or set your options appropriately. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: When I test that code, it works fine (although it's missing a space in `newString`).

Comment: @Clive no. this code is fine. Perhaps you are thinking of `String.matches()` which match the whole string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, except there's too much of it. Try this instead:

```
public String moveLastUpdateToFirstLine(String venueConfigurationStr) {
    return venueConfigurationStr.replaceAll("(.*)(last_update : \\d+ )(.*)", "$2$1$3");
}
```

Note: This also fixes the bug you have in your code regarding spaces.

Comment: btw, how would you fix my regex?

Comment: @elad if you mean the spaces thing, do as I did: capture an space after the number in your group. BTW, your approach doesn't need any brackets - just use `group(0)` or just `group()`

Comment: Thanks, please see my update - how can i fix this for multi-line string?